# Complete Canvas is filled on fill command

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm really not sure what is wrong on this one so I will post all of the code on the bottom.

I've started trying to make a simple animation program [like this](http://www.theanimator.co.uk), but whenever I try to draw a frame it instead fills the whole canvas.

Here is the code

You should probably clear the board before testing the function, too.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Drawing</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="container" width="500" height="500" style="border: 3px solid black"></canvas><br>
  <button onClick="colorChange()">Change the color</button>
  <button onClick="colorChange('erase')">Eraser</button>
  <button onClick="colorChange('pen')">Pen</button>
  <button onClick="bcClear('clear')">Clear</button>
  <button onClick="bcClear()">Change Background</button><br> Width: <input type="range" min="5" max="100" value="10" step="5" onChange="chWidth(this.value)" />
  <!--New method -- this object -->
  <button onClick="drawFrame()">Draw frame</button>
  <script>
    //variables for drawing
    var width = 10,
      color = "black",
      bc = "white";
    var cel = document.getElementById("container");
    var canvas = cel.getContext("2d");
    var clickd = false; //if clicked

    //variables for animating
    frame = 0;
    frames = [
      []
    ]; //frames: [ [frame1 circles, seperate by space] [frame2] ]

    //events
    cel.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
      clickd = true;
      drawSomething(e);
    }, false); //draw dot, make clicking true for dragging
    cel.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
      clickd = false;
    }, false); //stop drawing
    cel.addEventListener("mousemove", drawSomething, false); //\/

    //draw
    function drawSomething(event) {
      if (clickd) { //if u are dragging
        canvas.beginPath();
        var newX = event.clientX - cel.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        var newY = event.clientY - cel.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        canvas.arc(newX, newY, width, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        canvas.fill(); //make circle
        frames[frame].push(newX + " " + newY);
      }
    }

    //clear, background color
    function bcClear(param) {
      if (confirm("This will erase everything on the board, OK?")) {
        if (!param) {
          bc = prompt("What do you want the background color to be?", "CSS colors only");
        }
        canvas.fillStyle = bc;
        canvas.rect(-3, -3, cel.offsetWidth, cel.offsetHeight);
        canvas.fill();
        canvas.fillStyle = color;
      }
    }

    //change color
    function colorChange(param) {
      if (param == 'erase') {
        canvas.fillStyle = bc;
      } else if (param == 'pen') {
        canvas.fillStyle = color;
      } else {
        color = prompt("What color would you like?", "CSS colors only");
        canvas.fillStyle = color;
      }
    }

    //Change width
    function chWidth(newWidth) {
      width = newWidth;
    }

    //draw a certain frame
    function drawFrame() {
      for (var i = 0; i < frames[frame].length; i++) {
        var coords = frames[frame][i].split(" ");
        console.log(coords);
        canvas.arc(coords[0], coords[1], width, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        canvas.fill();
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Might it have anything to do with the fact that you are using `canvas.fill`? That sounds like a command to fill the whole canvas to me, but I'm not familiar with canvasses, so...

Comment: actually never mind that was a noob comment.

Comment: Didn't tried your code at all but at first sight you forgot a beginPath in the drawFrame loop. Each fill() will reuse the whole Path drawn from the last beginPath call (including your bc rect if it was called before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I forgot to add a `beginPath();` before I drew those circles and the fill was following my previous paths. New and Improved code!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Drawing</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="container" width="500" height="500" style="border: 3px solid black"></canvas><br>
  <button onClick="colorChange()">Change the color</button>
  <button onClick="colorChange('erase')">Eraser</button>
  <button onClick="colorChange('pen')">Pen</button>
  <button onClick="bcClear('clear')">Clear</button>
  <button onClick="bcClear()">Change Background</button><br> Width: <input type="range" min="5" max="100" value="10" step="5" onChange="chWidth(this.value)" />
  <!--New method -- this object -->
  <button onClick="drawFrame()">Draw frame</button>
  <script>
    //variables for drawing
    var width = 10,
      color = "black",
      bc = "white";
    var cel = document.getElementById("container");
    var canvas = cel.getContext("2d");
    var clickd = false; //if clicked

    //variables for animating
    frame = 0;
    frames = [
      []
    ]; //frames: [ [frame1 circles, seperate by space] [frame2] ]

    //events
    cel.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
      clickd = true;
      drawSomething(e);
    }, false); //draw dot, make clicking true for dragging
    cel.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
      clickd = false;
    }, false); //stop drawing
    cel.addEventListener("mousemove", drawSomething, false); //\/

    //draw
    function drawSomething(event) {
      if (clickd) { //if u are dragging
        canvas.beginPath();
        var newX = event.clientX - cel.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        var newY = event.clientY - cel.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        canvas.arc(newX, newY, width, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        canvas.fill(); //make circle
        frames[frame].push(newX + " " + newY);
      }
    }

    //clear, background color
    function bcClear(param) {
      if (confirm("This will erase everything on the board, OK?")) {
        if (!param) {
          bc = prompt("What do you want the background color to be?", "CSS colors only");
        }
        canvas.fillStyle = bc;
        canvas.rect(-3, -3, cel.offsetWidth, cel.offsetHeight);
        canvas.fill();
        canvas.fillStyle = color;
      }
    }

    //change color
    function colorChange(param) {
      if (param == 'erase') {
        canvas.fillStyle = bc;
      } else if (param == 'pen') {
        canvas.fillStyle = color;
      } else {
        color = prompt("What color would you like?", "CSS colors only");
        canvas.fillStyle = color;
      }
    }

    //Change width
    function chWidth(newWidth) {
      width = newWidth;
    }

    //draw a certain frame
    function drawFrame() {
      for (var i = 0; i < frames[frame].length; i++) {
        var coords = frames[frame][i].split(" ");
        console.log(coords);
        canvas.beginPath();
        canvas.arc(coords[0], coords[1], width, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        canvas.fill();
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```